# how to play audio file depending on the position of UIimageview which is moving by accelerometer

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I wrote the following code
But still the Audio part is not responding

```
#import "AccelerometerViewController.h"

@implementation AccelerometerViewController

@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize player;
- (void)viewDidLoad {


 UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = self;
    accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;   

 carRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    delta = CGPointMake(12.0,4.0);
    translation = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);       

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {


    if (acceleration.x>0) delta.x = 2; else delta.x = -2;
    if (acceleration.y>0) delta.y = -2; else delta.y = 2;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"translate" context:nil];

 imageView.transform =
 CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translation.x, translation.y);   
 translation.x = translation.x + delta.x;
 translation.y = translation.y + delta.y;   

    [UIView commitAnimations];   

    if (imageView.center.x + translation.x > 320 - carRadius ||
        imageView.center.x + translation.x < carRadius) {
        translation.x -= delta.x;
    }


    if (imageView.center.y + translation.y > 460 - carRadius ||
        imageView.center.y + translation.y < carRadius) {
        translation.y -= delta.y;
    }  

 //playing Audio file to show warning if my car moved on to another lane 


 if (imageView.center.x + translation.x > 160) 


 {

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tone" ofType:@"m4r"];
  NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

  AVAudioPlayer *p =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
         initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
  [file release];

  self.player = p;
  [p release];

  [player prepareToPlay];
  [player setDelegate:self];
  [self.player play];


 }
 }
```

Can any one please help me

Comment: Is the if statement if (imageView.center.x + translation.x > 160) being called properly? Add NSLog(@"playing warning audio"); or something to test. What errors, if any, are you getting? Also, why are you testing for the center + translation? As I understand it, you are going to be moving the car, so why not just test the center position after moving the car?

Comment: yes its working properly when i test with NSLog messaging ,but when i am trying to play audio its getting struck.

Comment: By "struck" I'm assuming you meant to type "stuck". Do you mean that the audio stops partway through playback, that it just doesn't play anything at all, that your app crashes, or that you get an error? Please provide any error messages.

Comment: Oh yes i mean Stuck. My app is not crashing. But when i try using Debugger, i realise that the code stops working from this line "NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];"  i dont know whats going on..

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things to check: Make sure you have imported the AVFoundation framework into your project and that you have `#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>` in your header file.

Move all of your [object release] methods to the bottom of the block. It should't make a difference but it's worth a try.

Are you using the latest version of iOS? 4.2.1 is the newest.

Make sure that your audio file is named precisely tone.m4r - it is case sensitive.

In the left sidebar, expand "Targets", then the name of your app, then "Copy Bundle Resources". Is the file tone.m4r in there? If not, drag it in.

Finally, why are you creating the AVAudioPlayer *p and then setting it equal to self.player (which I assume you've defined in your header file)? Instead, in your header file in @interface declare `AVAudioPlayer *player;` if you haven't already. After the @interface block but before the @end add `@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;` if you haven't already.

Replace

```
AVAudioPlayer *p =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil]; 
[file release];

self.player = p;
[p release];
```

with

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
[file release];
```

Edits:

•You don't need `[player setDelegate:self];`
•Make sure you have `self.player`, not just `player` (shouldn't make a difference but it's more descriptive).
•I created a totally new, blank project to test your/my code. See below.

AudioTesterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface AudioTesterViewController : UIViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *player;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;

- (IBAction)playAudio;

@end
```

AudioTesterViewController.m:

```
#import "AudioTesterViewController.h"

@implementation AudioTesterViewController

@synthesize player;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (IBAction)playAudio {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tone" ofType:@"m4r"];

    NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    [path release];

    self.player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

    [file release];

    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    [self.player play];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Notes:
-(IBAction)playAudio is called by a button I made in Interface Builder, but you can, of course, just make it a void function or copy the code into another function instead.
If this code doesn't work, try clicking in the menu bar Build->Clean and then running the project.

Here is my file structure: [image]

Comment: I have imported the frame work and added it . I have declared *player, I'm using both 3.2.1 and also 4.2.1 in two different computers and also tried replcaing the code ... Still the Audio thig is not responding...

Comment: Even i have tested normal Audio tester code. But when using with Accelerometer positioning the UI Image , its not responding. there is some thing missing which we r unable to findout.